# Trigger to update child with new parent id

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, custom-object, controller

I have a requirement where the child record (Account_Transfer_Policy__c) should be updated with new Parent record (Account_Transfer__c) if the **district_from__c** of current parent do not match with **district_Acct_Code__c** of child record.

This new parent update will be done when District_from__c of any Account Transfer record and District_Acct_Code__c of child matches

Now, below is my trigger

```
trigger ATwithATP on Account_Transfer_Policy__c (after insert) {
    Map<Id,Account_Transfer__c> mapIDWithAccount = new Map<Id,Account_Transfer__c>();
    Map<string,Account_Transfer__c> mapATwithATP = new Map<string,Account_Transfer__c>();

    for (Account_Transfer__c acc : [select id,District_From__c from Account_Transfer__c where District_From__c != Null and createddate = TODAY ORDER BY createddate DESC ]){
       
        mapATwithATP.put(acc.District_From__c,acc);
    }
    for(Account_Transfer_Policy__c c : trigger.new){
        
        if(c.Account_Transfer__c !=null && c.Policy__r.District_Acct_Code__c != c.Account_Transfer__r.District_From__c){
            if(mapATwithATP.containsKey(c.District_Acct_Code__c)){
                c.Account_Transfer__c = mapATwithATP.get(c.District_Acct_Code__c).Id;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm not getting any error but the child is not updating with new parent record.
Can anyone please suggest any changes in my code if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic updates without DML only happens when:

- You are working in a `before` trigger context
- And you are making modifications to the instance of a record stored in `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap`

If you need the Id of a newly inserted record to perform a query, then you'd have no choice but to use an `after insert` trigger. That doesn't appear to be the case here though.

You either need to change your trigger to work on `before insert`, or make an explicit DML `update`.

Comment: It didnt work with both before insert and after insert Derek.

Comment: @SK_112 Then you need to capture some debug logs and do some investigation and basic debugging. If, for example, the soql query feeding your soql for loop that populates `mapATwithATP` returns 0 rows (the number of rows returned by each query is included in the debug log at the default log levels), then you'll never execute the `c.Account_Transfer__c = mapATwithATP.get(c.District_Acct_Code__c).Id;` line.

Comment: I have around 10 records which are created today and those records were returned in the query mapATwithATP.
I'm wondering what did i miss here.